# (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) ERROR

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection-string, web-config

I'M getting crazied for that ERROR

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

MY Connection Poroperties for VS.NET 2008 Server Explorer

Connection String:

```
Data Source=GOKTUG-PC;Initial Catalog=BILIN;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False
```

Provider = .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server

There is no problem at server explorer connection

MY Connection String is

```
<add name="BilinCnnStr1" connectionString="Data Source=GOKTUG-PC;Initial Catalog=BILIN;Integrated Security=SSPI;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=60;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

I think i have tried everything about that stuation and tried steps from the link at the below.
Please Answer question if you have solve that problem...

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: Have you tried connecting using Enterprise Manager of SQL Server 2008?

Comment: yes i have tried... That connects clearly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is with Integrated Security.

You need to make sure you are running the website with a user that has permissions on the DB.

Comment: should i make that for local using?

Comment: You get an entirely different error with user credentials mismatch (even with integrated security). This error means the application can't even *find* the SQL instance.